# cannot get the exact charset using file_get_html

Tags: php, ajax, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to get details from a website using file_get_html of simple html dom. The link i tried is : http://dns.marnet.net.mk/registar.php?dom=test.mk

what i get is full of question marks

```
������ ������������ ������: 
test.com.mk
test.mk
�������� �� �������: test.mk [ ����� ��:15507 ]
���� �� ���� � ������� ��������������: 24-02-2013
���� �� ������������ �� �������:

24-02-2009
����� ��� �� ������������:

��� ��������� �������-������ ����� ������, ������� �� �����������, ���������, �������� � ������
������ �� ������������:

���. ����� �������� ��. 15/10, ������
��� �� ������������:

4030006605991
�������� �� ������������:

02/3114-001

��������������� �������
���:

����� ���������
e-mail:

zivko@prologistics.com
�������:

02/3114-000
�������� �������
���:

����� ���������
e-mail:

boris@proinformatics.com
�������:

02/3114-002
������� �����������
���
IP
ns2.powweb.com  65.254.254.134
ns1.powweb.com  65.254.254.135
```

How can i get the original characters used in the site ?

Answer (score 2):

I found out the solution.

I added this after the file_get_html command.

```
$html=mb_convert_encoding($html,'utf8','windows-1251');
```

This converted my charset as required.

Thanks for everyone who replied.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked the charset on the page when viewing the source:
It gave me this :

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">`

Comment: $html=mb_convert_encoding($html,'utf8','windows-1251');

This did the trick.